# "The system cannot find the path specified" for webpack in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, git, webpack, yarnpkg

I typically use git bash to run `npm start` in my webpack-enabled project directory. This works fine.

However, if I open the regular Windows command prompt and do the same, I get the following:

```
"$basedir/../../Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/.bin/webpack.cmd"   "$@"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

There is a file at the indicated path, and its contents is

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
)
```

This is something I'm trying to get set up so that other users can run `npm start` who are on Windows and want to run simple Windows scripts that include the command without having to rewrite their existing scripts to run in git bash.

I added webpack and all other dependencies via yarn.  Is it possible there's a yarn setting I'm missing or some path variable that will need to be added/modified when the other users install yarn?

Why would it behave differently with the same files when running via cmd vs git bash?